# Загрузка библиотек через composer

Tags: php, ssh, drupal, composer

Установлен composer на хостинг, мне необходимо залить обновления библиотек для Drupal.

Пожалуйста, подскажите порядок действий и необходимые команды.

Comment: `composer update`

Comment: Не сам composer обновить а сторонние библиотеки шаблона

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужны только обновления библиотек от одного из поставщиков, то можно выполнить данную команду:

```
composer update drupal/*
```

Если нужно просто обновить вообще все компоненты, то достаточно вызвать следующую команду

```
composer update
```

Если вам просто нужно установить зависимости из composer.json, то достаточно использовать команду

```
composer install
```

Если в вашем приложении вообще не используется composer и вы хотите магически обновить код библиотек, то ничего не выйдет.